# Can I use a SD card as cache instead of a Solid State Drive 

Tags: windows, ssd, sd-card

I just installed a solid state drive a few days ago and I have been reading about how to preserve the file of it. I am running Windows 8 and my SSD has 256G of storage. I am using a laptop and cannot carry an external hard drive connected to my laptop to hold cache, temp files etc. I was wondering if a SD card would work. So I would use the SD card to hold cache, temp files and maybe index files from Windows, would this work and be effective (since I believe sd cards will also wear out)?

Comment: SD cards are slow, that will slow windows down, beating the purpose of a SSD.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. What would it have to do in order for you to consider it to have worked?

Comment: As @HackToHell mentioned, SD cards are ***SLOW, SLOW, SLOW***.  Telling you YES in any answer below is a bad idea.  If you use an external USB 3.x drive, it won't suck (as much).

Answer (score 1):

I use a SanDisk Mini Cruzer for ReadyBoost and some temp files. So what it if wears out FIVE years from now? I have a normal HD in my laptop, although flash drives are really cheap now.

Just so you know that you do not need anything else for your rig. The Flash disk will be much slower than the SSD drive and therefore is not needed.

Best to just max out the memory (RAM).